# Blackberry simulator debugger attach failed

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am running the Eclipse 3.5 with the Blackberry Eclipse Plugin, and I have running that for months, but suddenly, out of the blue, the debugger is not able to attach to the simulator anymore. I have no idea what has caused it. I have disabled my firewall. Still fails, with no error messages. Anyone has any clues on how to fix this?

Comment: try cleaning up the simulator and restart eclipse

Comment: Defiantly run clean, there is a clean simulator option in eclipse under Project->Blackberry->Clean Simulator.  Also are you using an existing project or a new one?  I recently ran into an issue where the simulator wouldn't attach to a new project because the name was being FormEncoded, so the debugger couldn't find it.

Comment: Select File->Reset on the simulator seem to fix the issue, dont know why it is different from clean simulator

Comment: I tried all the above, nothing seemed to work, but it did work after i restarted my computer. Isn't there any other way out?

Answer (score 0):

Simply restart your machine, this will solve the issue